# Upgrade to gcc-4.9 broke clang++

Tags: upgrade, gcc, clang

Recently I have upgraded to gcc-4.9 but it totally broke my clang++ and I am unable to compile anything. Error I am getting:

```
In file included from src/tester.cpp:11:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/progress.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/timer.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config.hpp:40:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/select_stdlib_config.hpp:18:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/cstddef:51:11: error: no member named 'max_align_t' in the global namespace
  using ::max_align_t;
```

Output of clang++ -v :

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
```

I have tried uninstalling gcc and clang and installing it again but it did not help.
Do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: I got the same stupid problem :-)

Comment: Actually I solved the problem in the end... But what the solution was I am really not sure since I just installed and removed a lot of packages.. And consequently it was ok.. :-( I am sorry I can't provide more useful info.

Comment: strange... :-) hopefully it is resolved somewhen

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Comment: Well as I wrote.. I installed and removed a lot of packages... It's been a while. Try removing packages even remotely connected to gcc and perhaps it will work eventually. If you found out, please do share the solution with us.

Answer (score 2):

`$ grep max_align_t /usr/include/c++/* -r

/usr/include/c++/4.9/cstddef:  using ::max_align_t;
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/cstddef:  using ::max_align_t;
/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:    max_align_t
/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:typedef long double max_align_t;`

/usr/include/c++/v1/ are files from libc++-dev so we need clang to use libc++

Simple compiler switch sorts this out

So if you get this error add this to you clang command line:  -stdlib=libc++

Answer (score 0):

There was a long standing ABI incompatibility bug between clang and gcc for many months now.  The problem made clang unable to link with existing system libraries.

The good news (as of 2016-07-27) is: ***it has been fixed in Xenial (16.04.1 LTS)***

For the interested in the details, the upstream bugs are:

- [clang++ no longer ABI-compatible with g++](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.8/+bug/1488254)
- [please merge llvm-toolchain-3.8 from Debian](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.8/+bug/1605291)